# Postgres Query to find similar strings

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a 10 million+ PostgreSQL (v16) table that stores address details for a person. I have to find the addresses that are similar to the input address and exceed a threshold.

We have tried module `pg_trgm` but a large set of matching records takes time.

```sql
select *
from address
where ARRAY['val'] && pentagram
and similarity(address,<input_string>) > THRESHOLD
```

- `address`: column for address
- `pentagram`: column with a GIN index which has tokens of length 3. (Generated using `show_tgrm()`.)
- In `ARRAY['val']` we are putting a token of length 3, generated for the input string.
- We are executing the above query for every token generated for the input string.
- We are collating the address coming from each token query.

```sql
explain(costs,buffers,verbose,analyze)
    select similarity('no 25 nethaji cly 9th cross st wst velachery velchry chennai tn 600042',address)
    from address
    where ARRAY['vel'] <@ pentagram;
```

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.address  (cost=2296.03..416822.75 rows=398205 width=4) (actual time=136.191..13181.323 rows=398415 loops=1)
   Output: similarity('no 25 nethaji cly 9th cross st wst velachery velchry chennai tn 600042'::text, complete_address)
   Recheck Cond: ('{vel}'::text[] <@ address.pentagram)
   Heap Blocks: exact=357144
   Buffers: shared hit=357254
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pentgram_idx  (cost=0.00..2196.48 rows=398205 width=0) (actual time=57.975..57.976 rows=398415 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (address.pentagram @> '{vel}'::text[])
         Buffers: shared hit=110
Query Identifier: 7037675894901615674
Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.158 ms
JIT:
   Functions: 4
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.370 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.573 ms, Emission 6.775 ms, Total 7.718 ms
Execution Time: 13216.714 ms
(17 rows)
```

```sql
explain(costs,buffers,verbose,analyze)
    select similarity('no 25 nethaji cly 9th cross st wst velachery velchry chennai tn 600042', complete_address)
    from address where ARRAY['vel'] <@ pentagram;
```

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.address  (cost=2296.03..416822.75 rows=398205 width=4) (actual time=140.682..6224.179 rows=398415 loops=1)
   Output: similarity('no 25 nethaji cly 9th cross st wst velachery velchry chennai tn 600042'::text, complete_address)
   Recheck Cond: ('{vel}'::text[] <@ address.pentagram)
   Heap Blocks: exact=357144
   Buffers: shared hit=357254
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pentgram_idx  (cost=0.00..2196.48 rows=398205 width=0) (actual time=64.489..64.490 rows=398415 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (address.pentagram @> '{vel}'::text[])
         Buffers: shared hit=110
Query Identifier: 7037675894901615674
Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.225 ms
JIT:
   Functions: 4
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.629 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.525 ms, Emission 5.670 ms, Total 6.824 ms
Execution Time: 6237.051 ms
(17 rows)
```

How do I find all similar addresses in minimum time?

Comment: Why not just use a pg_trgm index?  You seem to be trying to write your own version of pg_trgm, but in user-space.

Comment: @FrankHeikens 400000 address is the result this query gives. There are further checks involved in code by which we can select or discard a particular address. If we can get more accurate results in any way, that will help us.

Comment: Do all the filtering in your query, in the database. You're now first selecting 400.000 records and then filtering in your application. That makes both your database and the application slow, by design.

Comment: @FrankHeikens The further processing is different. It's not dependent on finding similar address. What I need is how we can optimally find similar addresses.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is very strange.  Usually you just build the index directly on the text column, and not store individual trigrams anywhere explicitly. show_tgrm() is basically just a debugging tool, I've never used it in production code.

the query you show is presumably identical to:

```
select similarity('no 25 nethaji cly 9th cross st wst velachery velchry chennai tn 600042',address) 
  from address where address like '%vel%';
```

Which should use an index `on address using gin (address gin_trgm_ops)`

Although I think it would be more usual to pick a threshold you want, then use the % operator, rather than pick one substring out of the query.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes. A few Doubts 1) But if we use like query, doesn't it do a sequential scan even if I create a gin index on the text column?
2) If I put a complete input string in like, will it give me better results?

Comment: 3) How do you get a list of similar addresses from this query?